# Why is class instance method resulting in undefined after invocation. Is Timeout function correct?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

aeri.attack / aeri.magicAttack results in the attack() function. But if I try to invoke the function it results in undefined. WHY.

I tried doing a Character instance to see if it was just the subclass but it's not.

PS if someone could tell me if im doing the setTimeout function right that would be awesome and I would love you forever.

PS PS I can't test if the timeout method is working because NONE of my methods are working.

```
class Character {
    constructor(name, weapon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    attack(){
        this.name + ' attacks with ' + this.weapon;
    }
}

class Elf extends Character {
    constructor(name, weapon, type) {
        super(name, weapon);
        this.type = type;
    }

    magicAttack() {
        this.name + ' chants ';
        setTimeout(function(){this.type; }, 3000);


    }
}

const aeri = new Elf("Aeri", "bow", "air")
const bob = new Character("Bob", "yawn")
```

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the output of your methods?

Comment: Do you want to print out the text? Or what's the point? If you wanna to print this you must use `console.log('your text');`

Comment: @sean yeah I wan't to see the output if I invoke them in the console

Comment: @Esdras omg, i'm so dumb. Yes I needed to return it. Sigh. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I hate myself

Comment: No problem @Mugs, I know how you feel lol. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons why the code from the original post doesn't do what the OP is expecting it to do.

```
class Character {
    constructor(name, weapon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    attack(){
        this.name + ' attacks with ' + this.weapon;  //  (1)
    }
}

class Elf extends Character {
    constructor(name, weapon, type) {
        super(name, weapon);
        this.type = type;
    }

    magicAttack() {
        this.name + ' chants ';                      //  (2)
        setTimeout(function(){this.type; }, 3000);   //  (3)


    }
}

const aeri = new Elf("Aeri", "bow", "air")
const bob = new Character("Bob", "yawn")
```

(1) The `attack()` method is missing a `return` statement

(2) The `this.name + ' chants ';` statement is not doing anything since the result of the concatenation is not assigned to a variable or passed to a method, so it's simply discarded.

(3) The anonymous function passed to `setTimeout` references `this.type`, but given [how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), the `type` is undefined in this context (because `this` is actually the anonymous function itself).

To see the results of calling the method, the following changes would need to be applied to the original code sample:

```
class Character {
    constructor(name, weapon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    attack(){
        return this.name + ' attacks with ' + this.weapon;    //  (1)
    }
}

class Elf extends Character {
    constructor(name, weapon, type) {
        super(name, weapon);
        this.type = type;
    }

    magicAttack() {
        const chant = this.name + ' chants ';                  //  (2)
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log(chant); }, 3000);   //  (3)

    }
}

const aeri = new Elf("Aeri", "bow", "air")
const bob = new Character("Bob", "yawn")

aeri.magickAttack();
```

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed and thorough answer. Really appreciate it! Is there a way to separate the this.name + ' chants ' and the timeout function but still return both? To clarify my goal is to have it output the chant and then a couple seconds later the spell.

Comment: Sure, the `console.log()` function receives the thing you want to print to the console, so you could say:

    `console.log(this.name + ' chants ');`

    `setTimeout(function(){ console.log('some spell'); }, 3000);`

Comment: You're the best. Thanks man. Part of me is ashamed for not thinking of this myself but I guess I just need more practice working with real problems to cement what i've learned.

Comment: No reason to feel ashamed, we've all been there :-) Have fun coding!

Comment: Also, check out the guide on Mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 1):

just add console.log in your code :

```js
class Character {
    constructor(name, weapon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    attack(){
       console.log(this.name +' attacks with ' +this.weapon);
    }
}

class Elf extends Character {
    constructor(name, weapon, type) {
        super(name, weapon);
        this.type = type;
    }

    magicAttack() {
        console.log(this.name + ' chants ');
        setTimeout(()=>{
           console.log(this.type); 
        }, 3000);
    }
}

const aeri = new Elf("Aeri", "bow", "air")
const bob = new Character("Bob", "yawn")


bob.attack()
aeri.magicAttack()
```